# How to use Ruby's asset_url in JS (Ruby interpolation in JS??)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Ok so I have a JS function that changes the image source, but I need to fingerprint that image source per Ruby's asset pipeline. In other words, I need to marry this code:

```
// JS code
changeImage("assets/How-to/" + step_to_remove + ".gif");
```

With the fingerprinting that's normally done by

```
# Ruby code
asset_path "How-to/#{step_to_remove}.gif"
```

The stopgap solution I have now is just to manually remove the fingerprints, but I know there's a better way than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.js.erb` to evaluate your scripts first as ERB:

```js
// app/assets/javascripts/my_script.js.erb
changeImage("<%= asset_path(step_to_remove) %>");
```

Comment: Isn't `changeImage("<%= asset_path('How-to/step_to_remove.gif') %>");` enough?

Comment: I can't get that to work. here's the error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/How-to/step_to_remove.gif` Keep in mind step_to_remove is a JS variable

Comment: Also the .js.erb wont' work because this is SUCH a tiny snippet I'm just including it in the view file

Comment: @james Well then what's the problem? Of course you can use `<% %>` in your views.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure if I'm communicating badly. I put @Vucko's suggestion in the `<script>` tag for my view. And it got the error that I put in the comment above. The error came about because WHILE the `asset_path` code worked, I can't figure out how to interpolate hte VARIABLE step_to_remove. As in, the image SHOULD either be 1.gif, or 2.gif, where 1/2 are the step_to_remove, a JS variable. Does that help? Thanks @meagar!